# pandas: generate a dataframe, column a: start till end date (months) and two more columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, addition, date-range

My question was to generic.
Ok, other try.
I want a dataframe with monthly dates in the first column a.
THen i want to go through the dates and fill the values in row b and c

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import datetime as dt

#try to generate a dataframe with dates

#This ist the dataframe, but how can I fill the dates
dfa = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date',  '1G', '10G'])
print(dfa)
#This are the dates, but how to get them into the dataframe
#and how to add values in the empty cells
idx = pd.date_range("2016-01-01", periods=55, freq="M")
ts = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
print(ts)
```

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need column filled by datetimes:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range("2016-01-01", periods=55, freq="M"), 
                    '1G':np.nan,
                    '10G':np.nan})
print (dfa.head())
        date  1G  10G
0 2016-01-31 NaN  NaN
1 2016-02-29 NaN  NaN
2 2016-03-31 NaN  NaN
3 2016-04-30 NaN  NaN
4 2016-05-31 NaN  NaN
```

Or if need `DatetimeIndex`:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'1G':np.nan,
                    '10G':np.nan}, 
                   index=pd.date_range("2016-01-01", periods=55, freq="M"))
print (dfa.head())

            1G  10G
2016-01-31 NaN  NaN
2016-02-29 NaN  NaN
2016-03-31 NaN  NaN
2016-04-30 NaN  NaN
2016-05-31 NaN  NaN
```

Comment: And how can I go through the dates in order to fill the NaN cells afterwards

Comment: @Jodahsh - What is logic here?

Comment: I have an excel list, which I filter with a date range. I like to use dates from your table. Then I want to do a calc with the items in the date range and write it in your table, so that the NaN will become numeric values.

Comment: @Jodahsh  Can you post new question?